# Delete method - Catch UnauthorizedException from Rails with Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, interceptor

I have an Angular method that deletes a user from the users table, but the authorization is happening in Rails.  If an unauthorized exception is thrown when deleting the user, Angular doesn't catch the exception, so it appears as if the request was successful.

From my research, this is dealt with using interceptors, but I haven't been able to get it to work.  I have the following Angular method and interceptor.

Is this the correct way to do this?  If not, what is?  If yes, what am I doing wrong?  Not really sure how an interceptor is supposed to work, and the docs haven't been very helpful.

```
service('UserTableService', [ '$http', ($http) ->
  constructor: ->
  destroyUserRow: (id, error) ->
    $http.delete("/users/#{id}").success(() ->
      # Do something
    ).error((data) -> error(data))
]).
factory('deleteUserInterceptor', ['$injector','$q', ($injector, $q) ->
    (promise) ->
      $http = $injector.get('$http')
      promise.then null, (response) ->
        if response.status == 401 || response.status == 403
          $scope.$emit("Unauthorized")
        $q.reject response
]).
```

Comment: What is the response from the server? 
I think an interceptor isn't needed here, you can handle this in the `$http`'s `error` method.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, but the request is coming back as a 200 even though it's unauthorized.  Solved it by doing explicit authorization within the destroy method.